# unix domain socket permissions and umask integration between root and non root users

Tags: permissions, socket, umask, unix-sockets

I'm trying to understand the permissions of a unix domain socket, when using an existing file, umask changes are required as well as the dir permissions.

If I create a world readable dir as root and open a socket with netcat:

```bsh
root$: mkdir /tmp/mydir
root$: chmod 777 /tmp/mydir
root$: nc -l -U /tmp/mydir/sock
```

Then as a non root user try to connect to aforementioned socket it fails, though the dir is world readable as per:

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html

> In the Linux implementation, pathname sockets honor the
> permissions of the directory they are in.  Creation of a new
> socket fails if the process does not have write and search
> (execute) permission on the directory in which the socket is
> created.

```bsh
root$: runuser -u user1 -- nc -U /tmp/mydir/sock 
nc: unix connect failed: Permission denied
```

Now by doing `umask 0`, and restarting the same socket again, it **can** be connected to from the non root user.

```bsh
root$: umask 0
root$: nc -l -U /tmp/mydir/sock
```

```bsh
root$: runuser -u user1 -- nc -U /tmp/mydir/sock 
ping
```

Furthermore modifying the `/tmp/mydir` permissions to `chmod 600` will stop the non root user from accessing the socket again.

```bsh
root$: chmod 600 /tmp/mydir
root$: runuser -u user1 -- nc -U /tmp/mydir/sock 
nc: unix connect failed: Permission denied
```

It's clear the dir permissions work as intended according to the manual, but why is umask 0 required if the parent dir has the correct permissions ? Is netcat still creating some sort of other file ?

Comment: I'm wondering why you think an ordinary file would work. It's not a socket file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025755/how-to-create-special-files-of-type-socket on how to create one.

Comment: Thanks @Bib / zevzek, I've edited with a comment the references to a regular file as a socket file. I was confused indeed. Still trying to understand why the directory permissions aren't enough.

Comment: You should never chmod 600 a directory unless your intent is to make it inaccessible to everyone.  Directories need execute priv to be usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed this in that same [unix(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) manpage you're quoting from:

> On Linux, **connecting** to a stream socket object **requires  write  permission**  on  that socket; sending a datagram to a datagram socket likewise
> requires write permission on that socket.

Of course, you also need search(execute) permission to all the leading directories from its path, just like with any other file.

The part you're quoting refers to *creating* a socket, which *only* happens when `bind(2)`ing to it, which is what `nc -l -U /path/to/sock` does. Again, just like with creating any other file, the umask will affect the permissions of the created socket (umask == 022 => no write permission for other users => they cannot connect to the socket):

```
$ umask
0022
$ nc -Ul sock
^C
$ ls -l sock
srwxr-xr-x 1 xxx xxx 0 Oct 16 18:35 sock
^    ^  ^
```

Binding to a unix domain socket always has to create it from scratch. You cannot bind to an existing file, that will fail with `EADDRINUSE`. Consequently, most programs (including `nc`) will forcefully remove any file with the same name before binding to it:

```
$ echo text > file
$ strace nc -l -U file
...
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 3
unlink("file")                          = 0
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="file"}, 110) = 0
listen(3, 5)                            = 0
accept4(3,
```

---

NB: both snippets talk about the on-disk "socket" special file / inode, not about the inode representing the active socket object (which appears in `/proc/<pid>/fd`, `/proc/net/unix`, etc):

```
$ nc -lU sock &
[1] 4424
$ ls -li sock
20983212 srwxr-xr-x 1 xxx xxx 0 Oct 17 18:01 sock
^^^^^^^^
$ ls -li /proc/4424/fd
total 0
43825 lrwx------ 1 xxx xxx 64 Oct 17 18:02 0 -> /dev/pts/4
43826 lrwx------ 1 xxx xxx 64 Oct 17 18:02 1 -> /dev/pts/4
43827 lrwx------ 1 xxx xxx 64 Oct 17 18:02 2 -> /dev/pts/4
43828 lrwx------ 1 xxx xxx 64 Oct 17 18:02 3 -> socket:[46378]
                                                        ^^^^^
$ grep 46378 /proc/net/unix
00000000ee8c0faa: 00000002 00000000 00010000 0001 01 46378 sock
```

Comment: Thanks your answer helped a lot, after playing around I figured out two things:

1. If the file exists its deleted as you said and recreated as a socket file. (I missed the  **s**rwxr-xr-x file type appearing), so I couldn't workout why it wasn't being deleted like you said. But it was...

2. Now the the new socket file has been created, chmod'ing the file gives permission to the socket after the socket has been bound to by the listening command. umask was only helping because the **new** file (socket) will be created with public permissions. Adding this POV in your post may help others.